# how to replace content in of <tr> in a <tfoot>

Tags: javascript, wijmo

i have a table that was created by Wijmo I want to change the content of it's footer

myfooter

```
<tfoot>
    <tr role="row" class="wijmo-wijgrid-footerrow ui-state-default ui-state-highlight">
    <td class="wijgridtd" role="columnfooter" scope="col" >
    <div class="wijmo-wijgrid-innercell "> </div></td>

    <td class="wijgridtd" role="columnfooter" scope="col" >
    <div class="wijmo-wijgrid-innercell "> </div></td>

    <td class="wijgridtd" role="columnfooter" scope="col" >
    <div class="wijmo-wijgrid-innercell ">**TW: 12,100** </div> </td>
    <tr>
</tfoot>
```

I want to change the TW:12,000 to a different content

Comment: Your HTML structure is incorrect. `<div>` does not close properly.

Comment: sorry that was miss type

Comment: I don't understand; do you want to change the content dynamically?

Comment: So go ahead and do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the table row using `document.querySelector`, assuming the element's attributes have unique values to select it by (otherwise use `querySelectorAll` and an index).

```
var row = document.querySelector('.wijmo-wijgrid-footerrow');
```

You can then use the row's `cells` collection to get the cells, and use `cells.length` to find the last cell.

```
var cells = row.cells;
var cell = cells[cells.length - 1];
```

Now you can use `innerHTML` or some other method to replace the content of the cell.

```
cell.innerHTML = "some new content";
```

You can also skip those intermediate variables if you want.

```
var cells = document.querySelector('.wijmo-wijgrid-footerrow').cells;
cells[cells.length - 1].innerHTML = "some new content";
```

See the section on [tabular data](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html) in the HTML Living Standard for more information on manipulating tables.